# How to select the max event in a repetitive process?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a process with repetitive events with an order, you can see an example in the table

| User | Event | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | Event 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| XYZ | Event 2 | 2022-01-02 |
| XYZ | Event 3 | 2022-01-03 |
| XYZ | Event 4 | 2022-01-04 |
| XYZ | Event 3 | 2022-01-05 |
| XYZ | Event 4 | 2022-01-06 |

I need to select those users that have been stuck in the second "event 3" (2022-01-05) but haven´t pass to the second "event 4". This is repetetive like I said before, it could be 3 "events 3" but I need to select the max "event 3" but for those users that their last evenet isn't "event 4"

Was using rank but didn't solve my problem and honestly don't know how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: athena in aws with prestodb

Comment: your example and explanation doesn't make sense. what do you mean stuck at second event 3 but haven't passed to the second event 4?

Comment: This is an example of a user who passed to the event 4 for the second time. I don't need that user, I need the user who is stuck in event 3 for the second, third or fourth time but haven't passed to the event 4.

Comment: how about you also provide an example of a user that does not pass the events?

Comment: It would be the same table but without the last row.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that you tried `RANK` and it didn't work. You should have shown your query. Maybe it is just a little mistake that would have been easy to correct. Or there is something essential about window functions that you have not understood and we could have explained.

You need each user's last row. You get this with `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK`, `ROW_NUMBER` or `MAX(date) OVER`.

```
select user
from
(
  select user, event, date, max(date) over (partition by user) as user_max_date
  from mytable
) with_max_date
where date = user_max_date 
and event = 'Event 3';
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly we need to select users whose 'Event 3' is 1 less than 'Event 4', we can use a couple of linked subqueries.

```
select
    e3.user
from

    (select t.user, count(*) count_event
    from table t
    where t.event = 'Event 3'
    group by t.user, t.event) e3
        
    join (select t.user, count(*) count_event
    from table t
    where  t.event = 'Event 4'
    group by t.user, t.event) e4 
      on e3.user = e4.user and e3.count_event = e4.count_event - 1
```